# Could not find or load main class org.scalatest.tools.Runner

Tags: scala

Created the maven scala project.
I had correctly specified all the configuration . But still facing this error.
any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post the maven pom file?  It'd go a long way toward determining your problem.  Also, if you can provide your folder structure, that would help.

Comment: due to some reason I cann't publish the pom file. and folder structure is src/main/scala/

Comment: While that's not particularly helpful, are you also, by chance, using java in the same project?

Comment: thanks @kondrak for reply.This error is due to org.scalatest plugin.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this error.
Its coming because I had make the entry for org.scalatest plugin and there is no src/test/scala dir and no test cases.After removing  org.scalatest plugin entry from pom file everything work fine.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone that comes across this issue in the future, make sure you have the following dependency in your `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
  <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```